# Why does Laravel Mix's extract method cause Sass to not compile in this case?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel project using Laravel Mix, Vue.js and Sass.
The following is the content of the `webpack.mix.js` file in the project:

```
 const mix = require('laravel-mix');

 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['vue'])
    .sass('resources/sass/vendor.scss', 'public/css/')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/');
```

This Mix file is properly compiling all the CSS and JS assets for me when I import all of my Vue components into a master Vue component called `App` as follows:

```
// Layout
import SiteFooter from './layout/SiteFooter';
import SiteHeader from './layout/SiteHeader';

// Pages
import Home from './pages/Home';
// And many more here...

export default {
    components: {
        SiteFooter,
        SiteHeader,

        // Pages
        Home,
        // etc...
    }
```

However, as I started to create a lot of components. `app.js` started to get too big, so then I switched to loading the components in `App` asynchronously as follows:

```
// Layout
import SiteFooter from './layout/SiteFooter';
import SiteHeader from './layout/SiteHeader';

export default {
    components: {
        SiteFooter,
        SiteHeader,

        // Pages
        Home: () => import('./pages/Home'),
        // And many more here...
```

This perfectly achieved the goal of reducing the size of `app.js` and breaking the components up into separate files, which is great, but as soon as I did this, the Sass stopped compiling into `app.css` and `vendor.css` files, and I had no styles on the site.

I played around for a bit and realized that if I removed the `extract(['vue'])` line from `webpack.mix.js`, then the Sass would correctly compile again and the styles would display correctly, but then `app.js` would increase in size by about 330k because of the inclusion of the Vue code.

What I'm wondering is: Why does having the `extract(['vue'])` method call in the Mix file along with using asynchronous components in Vue cause the Sass to not be compiled, and more importantly, is there a way to pull the Vue code out into a separate `vendor.js` file as well as get the Sass to properly compile when Vue components are asynchronously loaded? Thank you.

Comment: This is apparently related to the following SO post I made later on, which is linked to a GitHub issue that a lot of people have complained about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288513/is-there-a-way-to-watch-two-laravel-mix-webpack-config-files-at-the-same-time-fo

Comment: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1879 - this is a known issue.